# Cordova build failed - google analytics and facebook plugin conflicts

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-facebook

Im working on cordova application.

After installing 
**cordova-plugin-google-analytics** 
(https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)

my build starts to fail with error code

`Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes`

After spending few hours on resolving and googling i'm quite sure
it's related to conflict with
 **phonegap-facebook-plugin** (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/)
because phonegap-facebook-plugin uses `android-support-v4` jar

One of solution was to remove `android-support-v4`, but this doesn't work for me (how it could if facebook just needs this jar..)

Another soluction was to create `build-extras.gradle` file with some content (can't remember) - also failed

Some of solutions was related to Android Studio stuff, i don't use Android Studio, i cannot use it. i'm buildind from command line.

Does anyone know another solution which i can try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue and attempted all the same solutions. Eventually I found this forked version of the cordova FB plugin from Jeduan Cornejo - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 - which has worked so far with a relatively seamless transition. I have not done full regression testing, but have verified both these initials calls work:

```
window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-xxx');
```

and

```
facebookConnectPlugin.logic(perms, function(resp){...});
```

If you do run into compilation problems after replacing the plugin, consider `cordova platform rm android` and then `cordova platform add android`